# Azure APIM liquid policy

Tags: liquid, azure-api-management

I have an issue with parsing inbound json body:

```json
{
  "id":"1234",
  "modelA": {
    "ids": [
      12, 
      22, 
      32
    ]
  },
  "modelB": {
    "a":"3",
    "ids": [
      22,
      32,
      42
    ]
  }
}
```

with policy

```xml
<inbound>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body template="liquid">
    {
        "aaaa":"{{ body.aaaa }}",
        {% assign var1 = '' %}
        {% for item in {{ body }} %}
            {% for id in {{ item.ids }} %}
                {% assign var1 = var1 | push: id %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        "result": [
            {{ var1  | join: "," }}
        ]
    }
    </set-body>
    <base />
</inbound>
```

Expected result:

```json
{ 
  "result": [
    12, 
    22, 
    32,
    42
  ]
}
```

There are few issues I am struggling with:

1. How to iterate over properties in the root? This is for arrays: `{% for item in {{body}} %}`
2. Assign t variable: `{% assign var1 = body.modelA.ids %}` result and then {{ var1 | `join: "," }}` result in `122232`. Why?

Comment: You can't iterate over JSON properties with Liquid template. You can do this with C#. Maybe it's also an option for you to change the request body to have an array of 'models'

Comment: Have u tried this liquide code `{% assign var1 = body.modelA.ids %}`